# Underfull \hbox (badness 1796) in paragraph at lines 101--103

Tags: badness

How can i fix this bad box? It is in a paragraph. Can anyone help me? Tex-studio highlights just below line.

The well-known stochastic programming (SP)

Comment: it's only a warning (and 1796 isn't _that_ bad) but if you want to change it to be less underfull you need to change its contents to have less white space, if you give no indication of the input it's not possible to say what needs changing

Comment: Try `\usepackage{microtype}`.